# Is this a shopping question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, off-topic, not-constructive

So I was tooling around in the late post review queue, and came across an answer that seemed odd. When I clicked through to check out the question, I was somewhat surprised to say the least.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/169559/1015495

Given that the question was asked four years ago, I'm assuming that if it was indeed considered NC/OT that it would have been closed already. I seem to remember reading something about how as SE evolved that the restrictions on questions have been tightened as the sites' roles have become more defined, but I honestly can't remember what the ruling was on old content that now wouldn't be welcome on the site. So I did what I always do in these situations, which is go running off to <strike>Mommy</strike> our lovely Meta community, and say 'This is confounding and confusing! Tell me how I should feel about this!'

Comment: Things slip through the cracks; many old posts are simply unclosed simply because they were fine when they were asked, and by the time that changed they didn't get enough attention to be closed

Comment: @BenBrocka I had a similar question I almost asked today when reviewing questions in the First Ports Queue.  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/316187/250725) has a new answer, but the question is clearly off topic based on current rules.  What stopped me is the number of upvotes on both the question and on several of the answers.  Should this be closed?

Comment: @psubsee2003: it should be closed; two votes and counting!

Comment: There there @mike. Would you like a cup of coco and a cookie for your troubles? :p

Comment: @psubsee2003 That question should definitely be closed, it's three years old and any relevant information it held is seriously out of date.

Comment: @Bart **sniffle sniffle** That mean person asked a question that made me feel funny! **sniffle**

Comment: @mikeTheLiar what I thought.... sometimes I forget that closed <> deleted (I didn't want to flag a question that is going to cost someone hundreds of rep)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is definitely a shopping question, and now off-topic to boot.

I've now voted to close it. It is never too late to clean up old questions like these; sometimes an old question like that slips through the cracks, it simply didn't get any attention since policy has changed.